# Loading images and reshaping resulting numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, reshape

Hi I am trying to reshape an array that is full of pixel data from images loaded with OpenCv. The resulting combined array is of shape (100,28,28,3)
and I am trying to make it shape (100,28,28) and cannot entire delete it with np.delete or reshape. Any help would be great! Here's my code thus far:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

hand_dig = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/digits/hand/*.PNG")
for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    hand_dig.append (image)

print('hand_digit shape:', np.array(hand_dig).shape)
hand_dig=np.reshape(hand_dig,(100,28,28))
print(hand_dig.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have given above it seems you have 100 RGB images of shape (28,28).
No, you cannot drop pixels as it may result in you losing a lot of information.
A better option would be to convert each image into gray and then stack it.

After reading image, add this lines:

```
image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```